# The one click publisher for c# did not keep my database populated after publish

Tags: c#, publishing

I just recently used the one click publisher from MS Visual studios in C# to try to publish my project. It worked smoothly but in the project I had the database was populated but not after I published it to CD and tried installing it. The database was there but no entries in it. Can anyone help?

Comment: What kind of database or you using? Perhaps the database became fuller and fuller when creating...

Comment: Check your publish settings for the database in the properties screen. By default it deploys an empty DB, you have to set it to deploy both the schema and data.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg ms sql server thats connected to c# by a data source

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Where can i find that setting? Im using visual studio 2010?